# Connecting Salesforce Authenticator on New Mobile Device- Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, authentication

I need to access Marketing Cloud but Salesforce Authenticator is connected to the old mobile device, Which I don't have access to. How do I disconnect the old Authenticator so that I can connect to the new device

Comment: Have you asked another admin to remove this connection on your user?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as suggested by Lukas you need to have admin role to perform this.

Then the user with admin permission has to perform the below steps to de-link the current authentication app.
[image]

1. Navigate to **Setup**
2. Users -> **Users**
3. Select your username and click on it to open User record.
4. Click on **Revoke** [this will de-link your user with the authentication app]

Once the above steps are done, the next time you login,

1. First a verification code [6 digit verification code] will be sent to the User's email address.
2. You will be prompted to add the new authentication method.
   [image]